# Flutter Apk size increase too much after implementing Zoom

Tags: flutter, dart, zoom-sdk

In my flutter project I integrated Zoom. It works fine but my app size increase too much.
library I used: flutter_zoom_sdk: ^0.0.6

I tried abi filter like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

But I am still having app size more than 60 MB in release mode, I am looking for option so I can reduce my app size.

Comment: I don't think you can do something about the apk size. The plugin using a library that is 92 MB, see https://github.com/evilrat/flutter_zoom_sdk/blob/master/android/libs/mobilertc.aar

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with this, it's totally fine.